# On Trello, how can I be notified whenever a new card is added to a board?

Tags: trello

I know I can subscribe to individual cards once they're created. In addition, I want to be notified whenever a new card is created in the first place (so I can subscribe to it).

Alternately, if I could automatically subscribe to any new cards on a board, that would also solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Subscribing to other entities, such as lists and boards, is covered in the [Subscribe 2.0](https://trello.com/card/subscribe-2-0/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/1260) card. It is in development as of this writing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no apparently way to get notifications with new boards created that you have access to. Even when you change notifications to instantly it doesn't show up.

I tried this using an organization and two members that I logged in with.